# MIPS System Time

Tags: performance, assembly, mips, benchmarking, mars-simulator

How would I get the current system time with the MIPS instruction set? I would like to benchmark some programs and would like to find the time in milli or nanoseconds that it takes for them to complete.

I am aware that I could run the assembly code from within C and time it with the C time libraries, however, I would like to do this is MIPS assembly alone.

Comment: Bare metal, or do you have an OS ?

Comment: I have an OS. Windows 7/8.1 But all ideas are welcome. (I am using a simulator)

Comment: Oh, so you're using a MIPS simulator ? Is it cycle-accurate ?

Comment: I am using the MARS simulator.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your simulator but a brief google search suggests that there is a count register which you can read to get the instruction cycle count.

Comment: When using the MARS simulator you could use the "time" function (syscall, v0=30). However this is the real time of the system clock, not the simulated time - not so good for benchmarks.